# How to use Flask context in Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-endpoints

I built a web app with a REST API using Flask. I take advantage of Flask's `g` to save the current user and pull the user's data I want from the datastore (the app is hosted at Google Cloud). However, I would like to implement Google Cloud Endpoints because of some of its advantages but if I call one of the urls in Cloud Endpoints I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Documents/Google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Documents/Google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Documents/Google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 95, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/Eatsy/Eatsy/src/application/apis.py", line 18, in <module>
    user = g.user
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/Eatsy/Eatsy/src/lib/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/Eatsy/Eatsy/src/lib/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/Eatsy/Eatsy/src/lib/flask/globals.py", line 27, in _lookup_app_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

How can I use flask's context variables like `g`, `login_required`, `current_user`, etc. for Cloud Endpoints?

In my code I store `current_user` in `g.user` and I have an endpoint where I get the `g.user` so I can get the id.

#### views.py:

```
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from flask import session, g, request
import requests

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    log.info('Received request: %s' % request.path)
    g.user = current_user

@app.route('/recommendations', methods = ['GET'])
def recommendations_retrieve():

    # This HTTP call is what I'd like to get rid off
    app_url = request.url_root
    usr_id = g.user.key().id()
    d = {'id': str(usr_id)}
    r = requests.get(urljoin(app_url,"/_ah/api/myapp/v1/recommendations"),
            params = d)

    return (r.text, r.status_code, r.headers.items())
```

My Cloud Endpoints file looks like this:

```
from views import g

@endpoints.api(name='myapp', version='v1', description='myapp API',
                allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID, endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID])
class MyAppApi(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(IdRequestMessage, RecommendationsResponseMessage,
                      path='recommendations', http_method='GET',
                      name='recommendations.recommendations')
    def recommendations(self, request):
        # I would prefer to use this, but I get the
        # "Working outside the app context" error
        # when I uncomment it
        #user = User.get_by_id(g.user.key().id())
        user = User.get_from_message(request)
        response = user.get_recommendations()
        return response
```

My Javascript function is as follows:

```
    loadRecommendationsFromServer: function() {
      $.ajax({
        // This is how I *would* call it, if it worked
        //url: this.props.url+"/_ah/api/myapp/v1/recommendations",
        //data: JSON.stringify({'id':2}),
        url: this.props.url+"/recommendations",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data.recommendations});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
```

The existing code works - how can I avoid having to make an HTTP request in my view handler and avoid the `RuntimeError` in the `MyAppApi` service when I use `g.user`?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/

Comment: You might have to share some code

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help us help you.

Comment: The question has been edited @GreenAsJade